# Start Service from library project

Tags: android

I want to start service from aosp libray.And I have used this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ExternalStorageFormatter.FORMAT_AND_FACTORY_RESET);
        intent.setComponent(ExternalStorageFormatter.COMPONENT_NAME);
        // Transfer the storage volume to the new intent
        final StorageVolume storageVolume = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
                StorageVolume.EXTRA_STORAGE_VOLUME);
        intent.putExtra(StorageVolume.EXTRA_STORAGE_VOLUME, storageVolume);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
```

and when I run the app.It crashes and not working for me. How to fix this

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: it is fatal error and from logcat  it point to startService(intent);
so what is wrong start services form library using explicit intent ?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full stack trace.